# MFC dependency in static library

Tags: mfc, linker

I use a framework called EzNameSpaceExtension for several Windows Name Space Extensions I support.

The framework is supplied as a number of static libraries and the headers automatically link the appropriate library (Release/Debug)(MBCS/Unicode)(Versions of Visual Studio).

I have recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 and (because their support is so unresponsive) have edited the headers to include the VS2013 library in the VS2015 build.

This is including the library, but now the link is trying to link mfc120.lib into the build (which is no longer in by build libraries).

Presuming I never hear back from the vendor's support people (last question I asked took 6 months to get an answer), is the mfc120 dependency something that can be replaced with the new MFC library? If it is, what are the linkage flags I need and what are the chances the code will function?

Answer (score 0):

You have to recompile the libraries too. The static libraries created their own dependencies to the runtimes. If you don't have the source code you are lost.

The problem is also that the linker linkage of some exports might match, but the binary layout of structures might have changed.

The libraries you have must match the compiler and debug/release mode, if they aren't only defined by entry points to a foreign DLL.

Comment: I figured they had a dependency, but I don't understand why.

If a library uses a C runtime function, as long as the calling convention doesn't change, why is there a need for a dependency at all.

BTW, the vendor have finally replied and are now committing to a VC2015 version, but in the meantime it I have had to revert back to VC2013.

Comment: The calling convention isn't all. Templates might change. Handlers and helpers for exceptions might be part of the CRT and might change...

Comment: If it is not too much work, you could encapsulate the libraries in a COM library and compile/link that against VS2013. Exposing the needed functionality as COM objects could solve the dependency issue not only with VS2015, but many versions yet to be released.

Answer (score 0):

Is the library deployed as sources?  If so - recompile it on VS2015. If not - your best option is to build your entire solution on VS2013. You can still do it from the VS2015 IDE (project properties / configuration properties / general / platform toolset -> 2013) assuming you still have VS2013 installed.  You'd get to keep the benefits of the IDE upgrade to 2015 but lose the benefits of the compiler upgrade.

It is technically possible to have a duplicate dependency on both 2013 and 2015 versions of MFC (and consequentially CRT, and perhaps OpenMP and more), but I would advise against it.

Comment: The libraries are not mine, I license them as libraries, not as source. So recompiling is not an option.

Comment: Can you ask the vendor for a vs2015 version?   If not, is building in the vs2013 toolset an option?